# Java Enums confusion

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to get my head around enums, some lines of code have me slightly confused.
This is taken straight from the oracle docs site but having a little trouble understanding a few lines of code :

```
public class EnumTest {
    public enum Day {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
   }
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
    this.day = day;
    }
```

The first 5 lines (class EnumTest) is quite ok, self explanatory really. What I dont understand are the last 5 lines of the above code, confusing. Could someone please explain their meaning within the context of the complete code below? Enumtest(Day day) is obviously a method , its the "this.day = day" and the preceding "Day day" I dont get .....

Complete code :

```
public class EnumTest {
    public enum Day {
        SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
    }
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
    this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {
        switch (day) {
            case MONDAY:
                System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                break;

            case FRIDAY:
                System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                break;

            case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY:
            System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EnumTest firstDay = new EnumTest(Day.MONDAY);
        firstDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest thirdDay = new EnumTest(Day.WEDNESDAY);
        thirdDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest fifthDay = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
        fifthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest sixthDay = new EnumTest(Day.SATURDAY);
        sixthDay.tellItLikeItIs();
        EnumTest seventhDay = new EnumTest(Day.SUNDAY);
        seventhDay.tellItLikeItIs();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but the code I have quoted here is from that same page :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's not really a method the way you think it is. If you notice, there's a new class called EnumTest, so what you're actually seeing is the constructor. And then the line below it, `this.day = day` sets the day for any instance of an object of class `EnumTest` using the input into the constructor. Sample code that could run in the main method would be:

```
EnumTest fri = new EnumTest(Day.FRIDAY);
```

Since there is no return type (i.e. void or int etc.) you can tell it's a constructor. Another clue is that it has the same name is the class that holds it.

Comment: The other way you know that it is a constructor is that there is not a return type.

Comment: Thanks jhobbie for that. Silly mistake on my part with regards to calling it a method. The java docs confused me because it clearly stated " You cannot invoke an enum constructor yourself" . So when declaring enums you can do it from outside of your current class? ie, for instance where you would put your imports? Last question, the " Day day;" line, what does that mean?

Comment: That creates a new variable called `day` of type `Day` which is later initialized in the constructor.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept my answer, for both me and you.

Comment: so day of type Day is a short way of creating a new variable in the same way x = x +1 could be said x++ ?

Comment: Not at all. `Day day` is create a variable of type `Day` in the same way that `int day` would be creating a variable of type `int`. However, the variable is merely created, (i.e. memory is allocated for it), it is not assigned a value.